# Using Google Drive Sync desktop application from multiple Windows 7 user accounts

Tags: windows-7, sync, google-drive

This question was asked about a year ago in [this thread](https://superuser.com/questions/561753/google-drive-for-multiple-windows-users) - I would like to know if the situation has changed.

This question is **not** about using multiple Google Drive accounts from a single Windows account.

We use 2 Windows 7 accounts on our computers at home. Each account has a separate Google Drive account, but if we want to sync each account with its own Google Drive account we need to either log off with with the currently logged-in account or manually close the Google Drive Sync desktop application before switching accounts. Otherwise, when logging-in to the 2nd account, the Google Drive Sync desktop application will appear faded in the tray and immediately disappear when the mouse pointer hovers over it.

Is there a way to make this work?

Note: both accounts are administrators accounts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same problem.  I was able to get it to work by turning off User Access Control under the security settings and now it works fine, but there should be a better way...

Comment: Thanks. That did help, though I'm wondering myself if there is a better solution... :)